# Perform task only when View appear on screen

Tags: swiftui

I have made this demo app

```
struct TestView: View {

@State var flag = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
                ForEach((1...50), id: \.self){ item in
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
                ProgressView()
                    .onAppear {
                        flag = true
                    }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(Text(flag == true ? "True" : "False"))
    }
}
}
```

I wanted to achieve that only when ProgressView() has been seen, then app title should be changed.

But problem is that ProgressView is immediately changing *flag* value.

Is it possible to make that only when View is on screen, some code can perform?

Comment: `VStack` initialises all of its children straight away, so all of them are deemed to have “appeared” when the parent is drawn. You might have better luck replacing `VStack` with `LazyVStack`?

Comment: That's because your calling `flag = true` `onAppear`, immediately changing flag value so it will change the navigation title.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question is using LazyVStack instead of VStack.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).